# ODBC creation for sql server fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, authentication, odbc

I have credentials to login to sql server database with windows authentication. Now, in another system, I am unable to create ODBC. the same username/password is throwing error.
Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a sql server user and try by using this.